# can't read multiple words from uitextfield

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to read the name of a product which is entered by the user in a text field, and add it to a string later. This works fine whenever the user inputs only one word, but when the product is more than one word, the program crashes. When I run the debugger, the value of the NSString product is listed as "variable is not nsstring". This method is triggered when the user hits return after entering the product's name:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn3:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    product = inputtext.text;
}
```

and this is part of the method that is triggered when the user hits a twitter button two scenes later (my goal is to have a certain message displayed already when the user is deciding what to tweet) [and yes, choice is set to either 0 or 3]

```
- (IBAction)twitter:(id)sender
{
TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[fmt5 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[fmt5 setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[fmt5 setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
if (choice == @"0" || choice == @"3")
{
    str = @"I just bought a new ";
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:product]; // line where it crashes
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:@" for $"];
    str = [str stringByAppendingString:[fmt5 stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]]];
    [twitter setInitialText:str];
}
```

How do I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of problems. Let's start with the actual reason.

```
product = inputtext.text;
```

is not good. If you use it later, when your view has already been deallocated, its text property is no longer valid. You have to retain it to have a reference to it. So change the above line to something like this:

```
[product release];
product = [inputtext.text retain];
```

Also don't forget to initialize `product` to nil to avoid crashes related to the first release call.

Secondly, your comparison isn't good.

```
choice == @"0" || choice == @"3"
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Use

```
if ([choice isEqualToString:@"0"] || [choice isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
```

etc.

Edit: also a minor design point. Don't reinvent the wheel by appending portions of the text sequentially - that's extremely unreadable. Browsing through NSString's class reference, you would have quickly found the following method:

```
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just bought a new %@ for $%.2lf", product, myDouble];
```